# How to write regex that does not match on a substring and ends in a string?

Tags: regex, webpack, regex-negation

I would like to write rule (to use in Webpack) that should match a string that does not contain the substring `xeditor` anywhere and ends in `.css`. If the substring `xeditor` appears anywhere in the string it should be discarded (ie. be a non-match).

I have so far come up with:

```
(?!.*xeditor.).*css?$
```

I tested in https://www.regextester.com/ but it still matches on strings like this:

```
globalsite/xeditor/styles.css
```

It shows that everything after `globalsite/x` i.e. `editor/styles.css` is a match. Because it contains `xeditor` in the string I want none of it to match.

How could I do this?

Comment: `^(?!.*xeditor).*\.css$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't the `^` only test for begins with?

Comment: It is what you need, to anchor the lookahead check at the start.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked great! Its not an answer so I can't mark it as such

Comment: `does not contain the substring xeditor anywhere` do you want to start searching from `styles.css` because it will match from there.

Comment: This is a duplicate of what are anchors used for `^$` and has been asked  hundreds if not thousands of times

Comment: Vol. 1, if it has not been made clear, `(?!.*xeditor)` causes the regex engine to move forward from the start of the string, one character at a time, until the negative lookahead has been satisfied, which, in `globalsite/xeditor/styles.css`, is when the internal regex string pointer is between `'x'` and `'e'`. An attempt is then made to match `.*css?$`, starting from that location. Adding the anchor `^` at the beginning pins the assertion to the beginning of the string, causing the negative lookahead, and hence the regex, to fail. Note also that `css?` merely makes the last `'s'` optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a string that ends in a specific  pattern but does not contain another, you may use a regex like

```
^(?!.*pattern1).*pattern2$
```

*The negative lookahead pattern must be anchored the lookahead check at the start*, otherwise, the expression is checked at each position in the string, the `(?!.*pattern1)` may match a location that is not at the start, somewhere in the middle, and has no `pattern1` to the right, while it can still be on the left.

Read more about why [*"Lookarounds (Usually) Want to be Anchored"* at rexegg.com](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#anchor).

Here, you may use

```
^(?!.*xeditor).*\.css$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HAs1bg/1).

Note the `.` must be escaped to be parsed as a literal dot character.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!.*xeditor)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible and then `xeditor`
- `.*` - 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\.css$` - `.css` substring at the end of the string.